# Convert Decimal Degrees or Degree Minutes Seconds to Meters in Java

Tags: java, unit-conversion

I am working with a GIS project.  Right now I have code to convert decimal degrees to degree/minute/seconds, but I don't have any idea how to convert decimal degree or degree/minutes/seconds to meters.  Can anyone help me to convert decimal degree or degree/minutes/seconds to meters in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You question might be really easy, or really complicated.  Can we assume a spherical Earth?  If so, you might be fine with the basic arc length formula:

```
Arc Length = degrees * pi * R / 180
```

Comment: Arc Length = degrees * pi * R / 180 in this r stands for ,

Comment: R stands for the radius of the Earth (a spherical Earth).

Answer (score 0):

How about [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/)?

> GDAL is a translator library for
>   raster geospatial data formats that is
>   released under an X/MIT style Open
>   Source license by the Open Source
>   Geospatial Foundation. As a library,
>   it presents a single abstract data
>   model to the calling application for
>   all supported formats. It also comes
>   with a variety of useful commandline
>   utilities for data translation and
>   processing. The NEWS page describes
>   the January 2011 GDAL/OGR 1.8.0
>   release.